# Are there any C# Bitcoin libraries and/or mining pool software packages?

Tags: mining-pools, c#

I was keen to write/launch a .Net pooled mining server as an exercise of getting into the Bitcoin universe.

- Are there any C# ports of the libraries needed to achieve this?

If not

- Are there any current tech mining servers that would suit my skill set, C#/Java?

I was keen to build out a site frontend & backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to look to build up an IronPython VS2012 programming rig

Stratum and Eloipool, As long as you don't use any Python features above 2.7 ,I  can write code that works in both CPython and IronPython, I will be able to debug it in Visual Studio under IronPython, then maybe do a sanity check with native Windows CPython and/or Cygwin CPython, then test on the linux box.

Looks like a way forward :D

Comment: Hi - I am looking for something like for my home serverz - You got any code?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome

1) [Here's an old project to start from](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinsharp/)

2) [Here is the Bitcoin.it wiki entry on pool servers, including the derelict PoolServerJ](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software#Mining_Pool_Servers_.28backend.29)

Mining is changing radically right now, with new hardware technology (ASICs) soon to be delivered which will likely increase the network hashrate by some orders of magnitude in the coming months. As a result, the protocols are changing to accommodate this increase, namely to stratum and getblocktemplate, if I recall correctly.

Good luck!

Comment: I have seen these and so far I can only find a link to the stratum protocol via a Pool Miner (Slush)..PoolServerJ Sounds like would be starting from behind the 8 ball to start with it etc

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin-Tool is new, might be something useful:

- https://github.com/mb300sd/Bitcoin-Tool/

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at this up-to-date C# bitcoin library: https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib

Answer (score 0):

We have an ongoing combined effort for developing a .net / mono based open source pool software;

https://github.com/CoiniumServ/CoiniumServ

All contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that works with the getwork protocol. too bad it does not support stratum yet
https://github.com/lithander/Minimal-Bitcoin-Miner